# Resize length of ssl key certificat, 4096 to 2048

Tags: ssl-certificate

By chance, it's possible to resize key length of certificat ?

From 4096 to 2048.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible. You have to generate new key pair and issue new certificate (it could be with the same Subject and extensions if you wish) but it will not be the same certificate.

Comment: ok thanks for this answer